# Deserialize Json Object having abstract class in java

Tags: java, json, json-deserialization, flexjson

I am using flexjson for deserializing json string

My Classes are as follows :

```
public abstract class Content{
int id;}

public class LoyaltyProgram{
Content content;
//
}
```

How can i deserialize following json object

{"name":"TESTER123","resetFrequencyHours":"1","target":"5","totalCount":"5","content":138}

currently i m using flolowing code for deserializing :

```
new JSONDeserializer<LoyaltyProgram>()
    .use(null, LoyaltyProgram.class).deserialize(json);
```

This throws following error :
[ content ]:There was an exception trying to instantiate an instance of content

Comment: Rule no. 1  of Java : You cannot instantiate a Abstract Class - and thats it

Answer (score 0):

You need to `extend` Content with a concrete class.

```
public class SomeContent extends Content {
}
```

That said, from what I see, your Content class only contains an int field. Both your JSon object and your LoyaltyProgram should probably take `int content` instead of `Content content` as a parameter.